# Exibir a Média em uma consulta SQL

Tags: sql, delphi, query

Quero realizar uma pesquisa em uma `query` até o momento consegui somente exibir o valor total dos registro.
 a ideia é mostrar a media de gasto.
Então seria o (total / quantidade) porem não consegui montar a logica:
o que tenho até o momento que apresenta o count de todos os registros

```
with AdoMEdOs do
begin
   Close;
   Sql.clear;
   AdoMEdOs.SQL.Add('select valor_total from ordem_servico');
   open;
   RecordCount;
   label5.Caption := IntToStr(AdoMEdOs.RecordCount) ;
   AdoMEdOs.Close;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito usando SQL ou na aplicação. Recomendo pelo SQL, pois é mais simples e mais eficaz (já que os dados estão no banco). Caso seja feito por SQL, então deve-se usar a função agregadora chamada **avg**, dessa forma:

```
select avg(valor_total) as media from ordem_servico
```

Comment: label5.Caption := IntToStr(AdoMEdOs.RecordCount) ;
como ficaria essa linha ao invez do recordcount qual seria função?

Comment: @GuilhermeLima, mudei a resposta dando um nome para o campo, chamado media. Agora você vai usar o seu componente de acesso ao banco, AdoMEdOs, para obter o valor do campo media.

Comment: Muito baca, era o que eu precisava !

Comment: fiz a consulta no sql e ele me retorna o valor 24 e no delphi me retorna o valor de 0 no label.

Comment: @GuilhermeLima, muito tempo que não mexo com Delphi. Certamente é algo que você está obtendo de maneira equivocada. Como você obtem o valor de um campo com esse componente AdoMEdOs?

Comment: label5.Caption := AdoMEdOs.FieldByName('media').AsString;
Apresentou o valor agora, era um erro mesmo..obrigado pela ajuda.