# Calcular Custo Médio de uma posição de ações

Tags: sql, microsoft-access

Olá, estou tentando criar uma query que calcula para todas as datas o custo médio da ação. A formula é descrita abaixo.

The Average Cost Price formula in T0 is: ((Accumulated Position T-1 * Av Cost Px T-1) + Qtty T0* Price T0)/ (Accumulated Position T-1+ Qtty T0)

Se o record é de venda, eu apenas subtraio a quantidade da posição aumulada e mantenho o custo médio

To perdido em como fazer isso, subquery não funciona para a mesma query, e não sei como pegar o valor de um record da mesma query. Qqr luz será bem vinda!

## Exemplo

Na tabela abaixo tenho a negociação do ativo Yum. No primeiro dia, comprei 9 mil quantidades ao preço de 88.97. Então o custo médio é 88.97.

No segundo dia, comprei 3 mil quantidades a 89.81. Agora tenho 12 mil quantidades a um preço médio de 89.18. O calculo foi:

((preço Dia 0 * Quantidade Dia 0) + ((Av Cost Price Dia -1)*(Quantidade Acumulada Dia -1)) / (Qtd Acumulada Dia 0)

Todos os dias que tenho compra, faço esse cálculo. Se tenho uma venda, simplesmente uso o preço médio da última compra.

Para calcular a quantidade acumulada usei uma subquery.

```
╔═══════════╦════════╦══════════╦══════════╦════════════════╦═══════╦═══════════════╦═════════════╗
║   Date    ║ Ticker ║ buy_sell ║  Qtdade  ║ SumOfNotional  ║ Preço ║ Qtd Acumulada ║ Preço Médio ║
╠═══════════╬════════╬══════════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 28-May-20 ║ YUM    ║ B        ║ 9,000    ║ 800,760.00     ║ 88.97 ║ 9,000         ║ 88.97       ║
║ 29-May-20 ║ YUM    ║ B        ║ 3,000    ║ 269,430.00     ║ 89.81 ║ 12,000        ║ 89.18       ║
║ 01-Jun-20 ║ YUM    ║ B        ║ 6,000    ║ 545,095.50     ║ 90.85 ║ 18,000        ║ 89.74       ║
║ 04-Jun-20 ║ YUM    ║ B        ║ 3,000    ║ 282,318.76     ║ 94.11 ║ 21,000        ║ 90.36       ║
║ 08-Jun-20 ║ YUM    ║ S        ║ (3,000)  ║ (287,970.00)   ║ 95.99 ║ 18,000        ║ 90.36       ║
║ 10-Jun-20 ║ YUM    ║ S        ║ (3,000)  ║ (284,558.70)   ║ 94.85 ║ 15,000        ║ 90.36       ║
║ 16-Jun-20 ║ YUM    ║ S        ║ (7,000)  ║ (654,720.91)   ║ 93.53 ║ 8,000         ║ 90.36       ║
║ 18-Jun-20 ║ YUM    ║ B        ║ 2,000    ║ 179,560.00     ║ 89.78 ║ 10,000        ║ 90.25       ║
║ 19-Jun-20 ║ YUM    ║ B        ║ 7,000    ║ 622,670.00     ║ 88.95 ║ 12,000        ║ 89.54       ║
║ 19-Jun-20 ║ YUM    ║ S        ║ (5,000)  ║ (457,820.00)   ║ 91.56 ║ 12,000        ║ 89.54       ║
║ 22-Jun-20 ║ YUM    ║ B        ║ 12,000   ║ 1,055,360.00   ║ 87.95 ║ 24,000        ║ 88.74       ║
║ 24-Jun-20 ║ YUM    ║ B        ║ 21,000   ║ 1,821,280.00   ║ 86.73 ║ 45,000        ║ 87.80       ║
║ 26-Jun-20 ║ YUM    ║ S        ║ (45,000) ║ (3,808,740.00) ║ 84.64 ║ -             ║ 87.80       ║
╚═══════════╩════════╩══════════╩══════════╩════════════════╩═══════╩═══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

```
SELECT db_TradeHistory.Date, db_TradeHistory.Ticker, db_TradeHistory.buy_sell, Sum(db_TradeHistory.Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity, Sum(db_TradeHistory.Notional) AS SumOfNotional, [SumOfNotional]/[SumOfQuantity] AS Preço, (SELECT Sum(Dupe.[Quantity]) AS SumOfQuantity
FROM db_TradeHistory AS Dupe
WHERE (((Dupe.Date)<=[db_TradeHistory].[Date]) AND ((Dupe.Ticker)=[db_TradeHistory].[Ticker]))
ORDER BY Sum(Dupe.[Quantity]) DESC) AS [Qtd Acumulada]
FROM db_TradeHistory
GROUP BY db_TradeHistory.Date, db_TradeHistory.Ticker, db_TradeHistory.buy_sell
HAVING (((db_TradeHistory.Ticker)="YUM"));
```

eu não sou expert em SQL e uso o Access pela interace e pois uso apenas para contole dessas posições, mas estou travado nesse problema, não sei se é possível fazer isso com SQL ou se tenho que tentar outra solução.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Exibir a Média em uma consulta SQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100270/exibir-a-m%c3%a9dia-em-uma-consulta-sql)

Comment: T0 é a posição inicial (tempo 0) ? T-1 a posição anterior ? Me parece difícil fazer isto no sql do ms-acess. Edite a pergunta para identar a sql e publique o modelo , um exemplo numérico ajudaria.

Comment: Oi Motta, isso. T0 é a posição do dia, e T-1 do dia anterior. obrigado pelas dicas, eu adicionei mais informações e o exemplo numérico do projeot. Por favor me avisa se é o suficiente. Abs!

Comment: Acho que ms-acess dificulta soluções do tipo totais acumulativos (running totals) e valores precedentes (lead & lag), o resto seria aplicar esta variante da média ponderada. Talvez seja mais fácil no Excel. https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-do-i-generate-a-running-total-in-an-access-query/   https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/access/available-lead-and-lag-function-in-ms-access/m-p/1401504

Answer (score -1):

Creio que com meu problema possa ajudar em algo:
Tenho um problema parecido, mas construi de modo diferente pois não achei matéria específica.
Depois de ter homologado a tabela de inclusão de dados segui com virtual tables no SLQLITE até encontrar um problema que já estou  a muito tempo remexendo nele.  Primeiramente deve-se ter em conta que tudo que se refere  a ações enfim ativos de investimento é aplicado média ponderada e nao média simples, aí que esbarra no problema em que se temos uma tabela de compra e venda em uma só temos que limitar o stop para médias a
cada lote vendido e zerado, sendo assim deve haver novamente um reset e começar tudo de novo se for

recomprar um mesmo ativo por exemplo. Segue alguns trechos que elaborei ate chegar a isso:

tabela fonte:

```
  id       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  idNC            INTEGER, 
  data_pregao     DATE, '+
  num_nc          VARCHAR(12), 
  C_V             VARCHAR(1), 
  tipo            VARCHAR(12), 
  ticker          VARCHAR(14), 
  qde             FLOAT, 
  saldo_qde       FLOAT, 
  tot_item        FLOAT, 
  tot_custos      FLOAT , 
  tot_opers_liq   FLOAT,         //calculado
  custo_item      FLOAT,         //calculado
  val_item_bru    FLOAT,         //calculado
  val_un_medio    FLOAT,         //vazio
  valor_total     FLOAT,         //vazio
  arquivado       DATE;
```

Determinar e Postar calculo da valor medio ponderado da unidade:

```
UPDATE tbtempor AS A SET val_un_medio = (SELECT 
        (SUM(round(B.val_item_bru,2)) / SUM(round(B.qde,2))) 
        FROM tbtempor AS B '+
        WHERE   B.C_V = "C" AND B.cod_ativo = A.cod_ativo  
        GROUP BY cod_ativo);
```

Com esta tabela fonte em mãos e com os cálculos auxiliares prontos
sigo  para a tab teporária para a carteira atual:

```
CREATE  TABLE tbcarteira  AS 
SELECT A.id,
A.data,    
A.C_V, 
A.tipo,
A.ticker,
SUM(A.qde) - '+         //ABATIMENTOS AQUI
                COALESCE((SELECT SUM(B.qde) 
                FROM tbtempor AS B '+
                WHERE B.ticker = A.ticker   AND   B.C_V = "V"  
                AND DATE(arquivado) IS  NULL),0)  AS qde, 
A.val_item_bru, 
A.val_un_medio, 
A.valor_total, 
A.arquivado 
FROM tbtempor AS A 
WHERE A.C_V = "C" AND DATE(A.arquivado) IS  NULL 
GROUP BY ticker ;
```

Obs Não normalizei ticker ainda ate eu encontra uma solução.

coloquei um trigger para quando zerar alguma venda marcar onde. Mas nao consegui prosseguir
porque ele enxerga a tabela toda por GROUP BY e nao consigo marcar uma venda.

Enfim, mais um módulo em que demonstro as negociações e detalhes delas.
Ate aqui tudo bem mas como delimitar quando um lote vendido para iniciar outro??

Eu deveria dar uma resposta em vez de uma pergunta mas talvez este modelo de para tirar algum proveito.
Penso ate em migrar para esta forma por acúmulo de resultados mas nao sei se vale o esforço.

Comment: Olá Cafi. Visando unir a ideia da média acumulada mais a minha ideia de abranger um carteira toda, pergunto: Este exemplo é só uma parte do projeto? Ou Voce sempre utiliza desta forma, inserindo o ativo para pesquisa? Estou tentando adaptar o modelo de media acumulada para montar a tb toda e chegar a um resultado satisfatório. Mesmo que voce esteja utilizando outra ferramenta encorajo a não desistir. Unirei esforços.